# Prove or give a counterexample: $ null\ T^m=null\ T^{m+1}\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;range\ T^m=range\ T^{m+1} $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

V denotes an infinite-dimensional vector space over F (R or C). Suppose $ T\in L(V)$ (i.e. a linear map from V to itself ) and $m$ is a nonnegative integer. Prove or give a counterexample:

$ null\ T^m=null\ T^{m+1}\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;range\ T^m=range\ T^{m+1} $ .

BTW: It is true when V is finite-dimensional. This can be proved using the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps.

I would be really grateful if someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false in general. Consider the left shift $L : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ given by
$$L(x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots) = (x_2,x_3, \ldots).$$

Then $\operatorname{null} L^n = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n, 0, 0, \ldots): x_1, \ldots, x_n\in\Bbb{F}\}$ but $\operatorname{range} L^n = \ell^2$.

Comment: And of course the *reverse* example $L(x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots) = (0, x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots)$ has $\operatorname{null} L^{n} = \{ 0 \}$, while $\operatorname{range} L^n \supsetneq \operatorname{range} L^{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Since I haven't studied Lp space, can I change $ℓ^2 $ to $F^\infty $ ?

Comment: @SkysubO Yes, you can put $\Bbb{F}^{\Bbb{N}}$, the space of all sequences in $\Bbb{F}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Got it, thanks a lot!